# C++ how to use a unique ptr instead of shared pointer, "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, binary-search-tree, unique-ptr

I'am trying to learn c++ and decided to implement a basic BST (binar ) that should be able to insert and read a complex data type value (Transaction class object). I need the BST to accept duplicate values so that is why I have made the node keys of type std::set, currently, I have each value in the set as a shared pointer, but I was wondering if its actually possible to convert these to unique ptrs in order to reduce the overhead of shared pointers. I have tried to get unique pointers to work a lot, but keep getting the "use of the deleted function", I then tried passing by reference and using std::move, etc gives me the same errors. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or is it's even possible? should I just stick with shared pointers in my std::set? thanks.

(sorry if it's a simple fix very new to c++ and such as challenging language even after reading so much documentation. )

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

// Complex type used for the BST
class Transaction
{
private:
    std::string desc;
    time_t timestamp;
    std::string value;
    bool isWithdrawal;

public:

    Transaction(const std::string& value, std::string reason = "None.")
    : desc(reason), timestamp(time(nullptr)), value(value) { // timestamp is current date/time based on current system

        // Lambda to convert reason to lower to we can identify elements easier
        std::transform(reason.begin(), reason.end(), reason.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
        
        // Check if reason is a withdrawl if so update the member fucntion
        this->isWithdrawal = reason.find("withdrawal") != std::string::npos;
    } 

    std::string toString() const {
        // convert timestamp to string form
        const char* string_timestamp = ctime(&timestamp);
    
        if(this->isWithdrawal) { return "-- " + desc + ": -£" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
        else {return "-- " + desc + ": £" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
    }
    
    // Getters
    std::string getValue() const {
        return this->value;
    }
    double getValueNum() const {
        return std::stod(this->value);
    }
    std::string getDesc() const {
        return this->desc;
    };
    time_t getTimestamp() const {
        return this->timestamp;
    };
    
    bool getIsWithdrawal() const {
        return this->isWithdrawal;
    };
    
    // Overloading comparision operators by value (transaction amount)
    bool operator < (const Transaction& rhs) const {
      return this->getValueNum() < rhs.getValueNum();
    }
    
    bool operator > (const Transaction& rhs) const {
      return this->getValueNum() > rhs.getValueNum();
    }
    
    bool operator == (const Transaction& rhs) const {
      return this->getValueNum() == rhs.getValueNum();
    }
    
    bool operator != (const Transaction& rhs) const {
      return this->getValueNum() != rhs.getValueNum();
    }
};


// The binary search tree implementation
class BST {
private:
    struct node {
        std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>> data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* t) const {
        if(t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    node* insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x, node* t) {
        
        if(t == nullptr)
        {
            t = new node;
            t->data.insert(x);
            t->left = t->right = nullptr;
        }
        else if(*x == getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->data.insert(x);
        }
        else if(*x < getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->left = insert(x, t->left);   
        }
        else if(*x > getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->right = insert(x, t->right);   
        }
        return t;
    }

    node* findMin(node* t) const {
        if(t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if(t->left == nullptr)
            return t;
        else
            return findMin(t->left);
    }

    node* findMax(node* t) const {
        if(t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if(t->right == nullptr)
            return t;
        else
            return findMax(t->right);
    }

    node* lookUp(node* t, const double& x) const {
        if(t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if(x < getFirstData(t->data).getValueNum())
            return lookUp(t->left, x);
        else if(x > getFirstData(t->data).getValueNum())
            return lookUp(t->right, x);
        else
            return t;
    }
    
    // Gets the first item from a multiset
    Transaction getFirstData(const std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& t) const{
        // Declare an iterator to first element
        auto itr = t.begin();
        
        return *(*itr);
    }
    
    // Loop through a node and return its values
    std::string loopNode(const std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& t) const{
        std::string result;
        
        for (const auto& item : t){
            result += item->toString();
        }   
        
        return result;
    }
    
    // Loops through all nodes and print out all values
    void printAllNodes(node* x) const {
        if(x == nullptr){
            ; // do nothing
        }
        else if (x){
            std::cout<< loopNode(x->data);
            printAllNodes(x->left);
            printAllNodes(x->right);
        }
    }
    
    // gets the root
    node* getRoot() const {
        return root;
    }

public:
    BST() {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    ~BST() {
        root = makeEmpty(root);
    }

    void insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x) {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    std::string lookUp(const double& x) {
        node* result = lookUp(root, x);
        if(result != nullptr) { return loopNode(result->data); }
        else { return "N/A"; }
    }
    
    void printAllNodes() const {
        printAllNodes(getRoot());
    }
    
};

int main() {
    BST t;

    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400", "Withdrawal"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit - test"));
    
    std::cout << "Searched value [1400], result: " << t.lookUp(1400) << std::endl;
    
    t.printAllNodes();
    
    return 0; 
}
```

UPDATED:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>

// Complex type used for the BST
class Transaction {
   private:
    std::string desc;
    time_t timestamp;
    std::string value;
    bool isWithdrawal;

   public:
    Transaction(const std::string& value, std::string reason = "None.")
        : desc(reason),
          timestamp(time(nullptr)),
          value(value) {  // timestamp is current date/time based on current
                          // system

        // Lambda to convert reason to lower to we can identify elements easier
        std::transform(reason.begin(), reason.end(), reason.begin(),
                       [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });

        // Check if reason is a withdrawl if so update the member fucntion
        this->isWithdrawal = reason.find("withdrawal") != std::string::npos;
    }

    std::string toString() const {
        // convert timestamp to string form
        const char* string_timestamp = ctime(&timestamp);

        if (this->isWithdrawal) {
            return "-- " + desc + ": -£" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;
        } else {
            return "-- " + desc + ": £" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;
        }
    }

    // Getters
    std::string getValue() const { return this->value; }
    double getValueNum() const { return std::stod(this->value); }
    std::string getDesc() const { return this->desc; };
    time_t getTimestamp() const { return this->timestamp; };

    bool getIsWithdrawal() const { return this->isWithdrawal; };

    // Overloading comparision operators by value (transaction amount)
    bool operator<(const Transaction& rhs) const {
        return this->getValueNum() < rhs.getValueNum();
    }

    bool operator>(const Transaction& rhs) const {
        return this->getValueNum() > rhs.getValueNum();
    }

    bool operator==(const Transaction& rhs) const {
        return this->getValueNum() == rhs.getValueNum();
    }

    bool operator!=(const Transaction& rhs) const {
        return this->getValueNum() != rhs.getValueNum();
    }
};

// The binary search tree implementation
class BST {
   private:
    struct Node {
        std::multiset<std::unique_ptr<Transaction>> data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;

    std::unique_ptr<Node> makeEmpty(std::unique_ptr<Node> t) const {
        if (t == nullptr) return nullptr;
        {
            makeEmpty(std::move(t->left));
            makeEmpty(std::move(t->right));
            t.reset(); // delete the pointer
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> insert(std::unique_ptr<Transaction> x, std::unique_ptr<Node> t) {
        if (t == nullptr) {
            t->data.insert(std::move(x));
            t->left = nullptr;
            t->right = nullptr;
        } else if (*x == getFirstData(t->data)) {
            t->data.insert(std::move(x));
        } else if (*x < getFirstData(t->data)) {
            t->left = insert(std::move(x), std::move(t->left));
        } else if (*x > getFirstData(t->data)) {
            t->right = insert(std::move(x), std::move(t->right));
        }
        return t;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> findMin(std::unique_ptr<Node> t) const {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if (t->left == nullptr)
            return t;
        else
            return findMin(std::move(t->left));
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> findMax(std::unique_ptr<Node> t) const {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if (t->right == nullptr)
            return t;
        else
            return findMax(std::move(t->right));
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> lookUp(std::unique_ptr<Node> t, const double& x) const {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if (x < getFirstData(t->data).getValueNum())
            return lookUp(std::move(t->left), x);
        else if (x > getFirstData(std::move(t->data)).getValueNum())
            return lookUp(std::move(t->right), x);
        else
            return t;
    }

    // Gets the first item from a multiset
    Transaction getFirstData(
        const std::multiset<std::unique_ptr<Transaction>>& t) const {
        // Declare an iterator to first element
        auto itr = t.begin();

        return *(*itr);
    }

    // Loop through a node and return its values
    std::string loopNode(
        const std::multiset<std::unique_ptr<Transaction>>& t) const {
        std::string result;

        for (const auto& item : t) {
            result += item->toString();
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Loops through all nodes and print out all values
    void printAllNodes(std::unique_ptr<Node> x) const {
        if (x == nullptr) {
            ;  // do nothing
        } else if (x) {
            std::cout << loopNode(x->data);
            printAllNodes(std::move(x->left));
            printAllNodes(std::move(x->right));
        }
    }

    // gets the root
    std::unique_ptr<Node> getRoot() const { return std::make_unique<Node>(root); }

   public:
    BST() { root = nullptr; }

    ~BST() { root = makeEmpty(std::move(root)); }

    void insert(std::unique_ptr<Transaction> x) { root = std::make_unique<Node>(insert(std::move(x), std::move(root))); }

    std::string lookUp(const double& x) {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> result = std::make_unique<Node>(lookUp(std::move(root), x));
        if (result != nullptr) {
            return loopNode(result->data);
        } else {
            return "N/A";
        }
    }

    void printAllNodes() const { printAllNodes(getRoot()); }
};

int main() {
    BST t;

    t.insert(std::make_unique<Transaction>("1400", "Withdrawal"));
    t.insert(std::make_unique<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit"));
    t.insert(std::make_unique<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit - test"));

    std::cout << "Searched value [1400], result: " << t.lookUp(1400)
              << std::endl;

    t.printAllNodes();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I need the BST to accept duplicate values so that is why I have made the node keys of type std::set". This makes very little sense. A search tree is an implementation of a multiset. It is not worth much if it depends on a different implementation of a miltiset. How do you get the very first multiset then? A search tree that admits duplicate elements is easily implementable without any such dependency.

Comment: in my application i dont ever need to find the first multiset

Answer (score 1):

- Replace all `shared` with `unique`. That is `std::shared_ptr` => `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_shared` => `std::make_unique`
- Since a `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied, you'll have to move it, so in all places where you copy the pointer, `std::move` it instead. Example in one of your functions:

  ```
  node* insert(std::unique_ptr<Transaction> x, node* t) {
      if (t == nullptr) {
          t = new node;
          t->data.insert(std::move(x));
          t->left = t->right = nullptr;
      } else if (*x == getFirstData(t->data)) {
          t->data.insert(std::move(x));
      } else if (*x < getFirstData(t->data)) {
          t->left = insert(std::move(x), t->left);
      } else if (*x > getFirstData(t->data)) {
          t->right = insert(std::move(x), t->right);
      }
      return t;
  }
  ```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o18bhP3vM)

Comment: ah thank you, i there actually any benefits to using shared_ptr in this scenario? also i plan to make all cases of Node* a uniuqe ptr, would this be the right call, or would it make more sense to use shared, as for example in my make empty function how can i call "delete t" with smart pointers?

Comment: @paigelarry342 You're welcome. Shared pointers have the benefit of being copyable - but adding copying to classes with unique pointers isn't much work. I prefer unique pointers for most owning pointer-situations. The `reset` member function deletes the owned object if you need that.

Comment: Thanks ive tried to make all the node pointers unique with reset for the delete. But i get 1 error for the Node struct saying "candidate expects 0 arguments 1 given", i pasted my updated code in the question, could you take a quick look?

Comment: @paigelarry342 I'd like to help but the amount of code in your question was already on the verge of being a bit too much and now even more so. If the first question you asked was answered by my answer, you could accept the answer and ask a new question. When doing so, remove everything not necessary and provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the one specific thing you are asking about. Not only does it make everything clearer, it'll help those searching for solutions to similar problems in the future.